# Hide string in binary at compile time?

Tags: c, string, macros, obfuscation, preprocessor

I want to obfuscate a particular string in the binary of a C program to make it harder to analyze. I *know* this will not prevent someone from seeing the string if running it in a debugger. Yes, this is merely obfuscation.

Every instance of obfuscation triggers a discussion saying it has no value whatsoever. So did this one! *I am aware that a capable and determined attacker will be able to recover the string. For the sake of the argument let's say I'm writing a game for X year olds and the string to be hidden is a URL to be called only once they beat the game and their name will be added to the hall of fame. It's reasonable to assume that most X year olds will not have skills that go beyond opening the binary file in a hex editor. Thanks!*

Is there some elegant way to do the hiding at compile time, perhaps using the C preprocessor and a macro?

What i have seen so far is [a suggestion by Yuri Slobodyanyuk](https://yurisk.info/2017/06/25/binary-obfuscation-string-obfuscating-in-C/) resulting in this:

```
#define HIDE_LETTER(a)   (a) + 0x50
#define UNHIDE_STRING(str)  do { char * ptr = str ; while (*ptr) *ptr++ -= 0x50; } while(0)

...

  char str1[] = { HIDE_LETTER('s'), HIDE_LETTER('e'), HIDE_LETTER('c'), HIDE_LETTER('r'), HIDE_LETTER('e'), 
    HIDE_LETTER('t'), '\0' };

  UNHIDE_STRING(str1);  // unmangle the string in-place
```

It works but it's a bit ugly.  Perhaps someone knows a better solution?

I'm fine with something that is gcc specific.

PS: For C++ there is [a solution by Adam Yaxley on github](https://github.com/adamyaxley/Obfuscate) but I'm looking for C, not C++. And there's a solution with a little helper program at https://github.com/TwizzyIndy/hkteam_obfuscator

Comment: You have multiple problems with the way this is done. For example, it's implementation defined (i.e. up to the compiler) if `char` is a signed or unsigned type. If it's signed, then e.g. `'s' + 0x50` will be larger than can fit in the range of the (signed) `char`.

Comment: Yes i'm indeed looking for a better solution.

Comment: What is the purpose of this "hiding"? And does it have to be done only for some string in the program, or all? And can you perhaps load (possibly encrypted) text file for the strings? But most important is the purpose, as it will turn your question from an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to something more narrow where it might be possible to help you better.

Comment: I want to make it harder for an attacker to see what my program is doing. The string i want to hide is used in `strcmp()` but i can think of another case where the string is a secret URL that gets called if someone reaches the end of a game and gets added to the hall of fame.

Comment: Then welcome to the loosing side of a game of whack-a-mole, I'm sorry to say. Security by obscurity never works. The best bets are to use a proper decryption library (statically linked) that can decrypt the encrypted string, and hope that you program never gets popular enough to get any attention from "hackers".

Comment: There are X% of users who know how to use "strings" or a hex editor and there are Y% of users who know how to use "gdb" (and have the time to do it) and Y is a lot smaller than X. So for X-Y% of attackers it works. There clearly is some value in this.

Comment: What do you mean with gdb? If someone is looking for your strings they will use a plain hex editor.

Comment: With gdb i mean debugging the program at runtime to find out the secret value of the string. With the (not very nice) solution given already in my question you will not see the string in a hex editor.

Comment: Sounds like you really want something more like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_work

Comment: How about a combination of writing these strings into a file with EBCDI (or any other strange) coding, using "objcopy" to create an object file from this, and linking it to your program? I don't think that the preprocessor is powerful enough to do loops over character arrays.

Comment: I bet Boost has something you can use, to do semi-complicated string processing in the preprocessor, at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

First, be aware that your issue is probably better covered by some legal approach (a contract reviewed by a paid lawyer) than by technical means.

Your approach is similar to [Caesar cypher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) (which has been broken thousands of years ago: insight: compute frequencies of letters; in human English, `e` is the most frequent one). Even the German [Enigma machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine) did a lot better in WW2. Read about the works of [Alan Turing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing) during WW2 (his team broke the Enigma machine encryption).

> Is there some elegant way to do it at compile time, perhaps using the C preprocessor and a macro?

### No, there is not

(and mathematical proofs of that exist in the literature, covered by *books* related to [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or cybersecurity or [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/) proof assistant; be aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem); Read also Berto-Caseran book on *Interactive Theorem Proving and Software Development* ISBN 3-540-20854-2)

The argument of such a proof is based on cardinality. You could also use a probabilistic approach: store in your program some cryptic hashcode (e.g. computed by [crypt(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) at build time) and ask from user input a secret key, etc...

Any professional hacker will be technically able (perhaps after weeks of work) to find your "secret" string. Or colleagues working on or with [BinSec](https://binsec.github.io/).

However, you could write some metaprogram generating your obfuscated string as C code (to be `#include`-d at compile time), and add into your program some deobfuscation routine.

> I'm fine with something that is gcc specific.

On large programs, consider developing your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) (perhaps starting with [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/)). See also the [DECODER](https://decoder-project.Eu/) project.

Be however aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem). Read about [P vs NP problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem).

Consider also generating some C code (maybe some `#include`-d header) with tools like [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp).

[Code obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) is a topic which has conferences. Did you attend any of them? Many papers exist in ACM conferences.

There could be also legal issues (perhaps related to [GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/)). You should contact your lawyer. In France, see article [323](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/article_lc/LEGIARTI000030939438/) du Code Pénal.

If your code runs on a computer connected to the Internet and interacting with a user, consider a [SaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) approach: you could ask some money with a [VISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_Inc.) card at every run (or once a month).... Your bank will sell you appropriate software and permissions.

> I'm writing a game for 8 year olds and the string to be hidden is a URL to be called only once they beat the game and their name will be added to the hall of fame. It's reasonable to assume that most 8 year olds will not have skills that go beyond opening the binary file in a hex editor.

I now no 8 years old kid able to do that, and those who do deserves to be added to your hall of fame. If indeed you are coding a *game*, I recommend putting the URL as clear text.

NB. The old [XPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_PixMap) program could be inspirational, and so can be [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) and Jacques Pitrat's last book *Artificial Beings, the conscience of a conscious machine* (ISBN-13: 978-1848211018). Feel free to contact me by email `basile@starynkevitch.net` (home) or `basile.starynkevitch@cea.fr` (office, at [CEA LIST](https://www-list.cea.fr/)) for more.

PS. Consider of course starting your PhD on that topic! In France, at [ENS](https://www.ens.fr/) or [Ecole Polytechnique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_Polytechnique). There are interesting related talks at [College de France](https://www.college-de-france.fr/site/college/index.htm). In Germany, [Frauhaufer CyberSecurity lab](https://www.fraunhofer.de/en/institutes/cooperation/learning-labs-cyber-security.html). Probably, the [Bundeswehr](https://www.bundeswehr.de/de/) will fund your research in Germany (but I have no connections there), and also [ITEA4](https://itea4.org/). Of course, you will spend three or four years full-time to find a good enough solution. Please publish papers on [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/corr).

Comment: Having an extra program for generating the obfuscation is adding complexity i'd like to avoid.

Comment: I don't see what artificial intelligence has to do with my problem, it appears you are merely spamming links to your project page. Also, i already gave a technical solution in my question, i am merely looking for a better solution.

Comment: ***There is no better solution***. Read any book about the Enigma machine! If you find a better solution, publish it, you will get the [Turing award](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_Award) if your solution is correct. And I am serious, start a PhD on that very topic. You could become rich and famous!

Comment: I am not an expert in cryptography, but during world war two, thousands of people died in relation to cryptographic approaches, and the cracking of Enigma. You definitely should start a PhD on that very topic.

Comment: I edited my answer to add links to some places in Europe where you could start your PhD. I cannot do more (my PhD was defended in 1990).

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
#define STRING "Obfuscated"
#define Makestr(i) string[i] = STRING[i]

char string[11];

Makestr(6); Makestr(5);
Makestr(9); Makestr(7);
Makestr(0); Makestr(3);
Makestr(2); Makestr(4);
Makestr(1); Makestr(8);
Makestr(10);
```

This will typically compile to the equivalent of

```
string[6] = 97;  string[5] = 99;
string[9] = 100; string[7] = 116;
string[0] = 79;  string[3] = 117;
string[2] = 102; string[4] = 115;
string[1] = 98;  string[8] = 101;
string[10] = 0;
```

If you look at the object file using `strings` or a hex editor, it won't even be obvious that there's a string at all.  (But if you step through the code in a debugger, you'd be able to suss out what it was doing soon enough.  No way around that, really.)

You could also perturb the individual characters, as in your original question:

```
#define Makestr(i) string[i] = STRING[i] + 0x50
```

Me, I'd worry about overflow, so I'd probably do

```
#define Makestr(i) string[i] = STRING[i] ^ 0x55
```

Now you get the equivalent of

```
string[6] = 177;
```

or

```
string[6] = 52;
```

, etc.

Obviously in these cases you have to additionally unhide the
constructed string at run time, of course.

With clang I had to use `-O` to force it to collapse the constants and not emit the original string in the object file; with gcc it worked right away.

If your string is longer, the randomly-shuffled sequence of `Makestr` calls could get pretty unwieldy, though.

Comment: Many optimizing compilers could inline and reorder the code to a compile-time initialization similar to `strcpy`

Comment: Yeah that works! But it is pretty error prone. I think i will go with the original solution mentioned in the question but with "OR 0x80" to hide and "AND 0x7f" to unhide to avoid the issue that @someProgrammerDude mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I changed the obfuscation to just flip bit 7.
Also i couldn't find a pretty way to do the encoding in the C preprocessor cpp at compile time.
I ended up encoding the string using this shell onliner

```
tr \\000-\\377 \\200-\\377\\0-\\177|od -t x1 -A none|sed -e 's/ /\\x/g'
```

or this Powershell oneliner:

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes((Read-Host)) | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -lt 128) { ($_ -bor 0x80) } else { ($_ -band 0x7F) } } | ForEach-Object { '\x{0:X2}' -f $_ } | Write-Host -NoNewline
```

and sticking the result into the C source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* flip bit 7 in string using shell commands
   tr \\000-\\377 \\200-\\377\\0-\\177|od -t x1 -A none|sed -e 's/ /\\x/g'
 */

int main() {
    char secret[] = "\xce\xef\xf4\xa0\xf5\xf3\xe9\xee\xe7\xa0\xf4\xe8"
        "\xe5\xa0\xf0\xf2\xe5\xf0\xf2\xef\xe3\xe5\xf3\xf3\xef\xf2"
        "\xa0\xba\xad\xa8";

    for (int i = 0; secret[i]; i++)
        secret[i] ^= 1 << 7; // flip bit 7

    printf("%s\n",secret);
}
```

I will leave this question as unanswered for now in the hope that someone finds a one-step solution instead of this two-step approach.