# How to write C macro definition to iterate string and modify characters

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I need to make some simple character modifications on compile time, for example instead of:

```
char text[] = "test text";
```

I want to be able to write:

```
char text[] = _MODIFY("test text", 10);
```

And I want it to be preprocessed as:

```
char text[] = {116^10,101^10,115^10,116^10,32^10,116^10,101^10,120^10,116^10,0 };
```

where numbers are ASCII codes XORed with constant.
How to define _MODIFY macro preprocessor?

Comment: Macros are basically a mechanism for text replacement. You cannot create loops or other logic with macros.

Comment: Do you really want to code the data absent a nul terminator? Why do you think `char text[] = "test text";` isn't compiled with the character codes? The `'t'` is just a shortcut way of writing `116` anyway, but more portable.

Comment: What kind of "add some simple modification" do you want to do after you convert the string into numerical values?

Comment: @WeatherVane my mistake - zero as last byte should be present!

Comment: @Gerhardh I want to XOR each character with constant number.

Comment: It ***is*** processed how you say without needing to take any action. Those letters do not exist inside the code. Anyway this `'t' ^ 0x40` is a perfectly valid operation.

Comment: So, your basic aim is to obfuscate your strings within your executable?

Comment: @Gerhardh exactly, obfuscate some strings using minimal effort. I will deobfuscate them in code. I don't want to use anything more fancy, because it will be run on very limited microcontroller device

Comment: @WeatherVane ok, the macro should then generate something like {'t'^ 0x40, 'e'^0x40,...,0}. Still, I don't know how to execute loop in preprocessor.

Comment: I would say, that is not possible using a macro. You might create macros for the string literals and store them in a header file that is created in a separate step.

Comment: I would say the easier way to obfuscate your strings is to prepare them separately with another program and paste them with a comment in clear (it won't be in the code) so you don't obfuscate yourself. For example `char msg[] = "qzhq"; // spells 'test'`. If you are making a product that works in say English, Spanish and French then you'd need a different approach anyway.

Comment: I know it is posiible to prepare the strings in separate tool, but it will be some pain to do it each time I want to make a change, and potential source of errors in maintaining the project.  That's why I'm looking into using macros. "In theory" it should be possible, because we are talking about processing contants here - before compilation. I found sth like https://gist.github.com/wowczarek/7c8121696f7373e126d0 but not sure how to use it...

Comment: That's not a compile time tool, but a way to implement a generic `foreach` at run time. I think you'll end up with code that is more complicated than it needs to be. Just make a little program that generates the required C source code statements as a small module to `#include` in the compilation. That removes the potential source for errors because the conversions are automated.

Comment: @PanJanek Running a separate code-generatic script which you launch through the IDE before compiling is probably the most sensible solution. The pre-processor is a blunt tool and it sucks for iterating through a chunk of data with arbitrary lengths.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide string in binary at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69927341/hide-string-in-binary-at-compile-time)

Comment: Can you switch to C++? This is way easier in it.

Answer (score 1):

The transformation you were originally describing is exactly, what the compiler does: `char text[] = "test text";` is just a shorthand for `char text[] = {116, 101, 115, 116, 32, 116, 101, 120,  116, 0 };`.

I don't think, that the CPP is capable of doing that on the string definition, because it works string-based not token-based. So it has now clue, what it parameters you give to a macro, it just performs text expansion.

What you can do, is this:

```c
#define LAZY_EVAL () // important space, stop evaluating macro until expansion

#define EXPAND(...) EXPAND_(EXPAND_(EXPAND_(EXPAND_(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND_(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define OBFUSCATE_CHAR(C) ((C)^40)

#define OBFUSCATE_STRING(c, ...) OBFUSCATE_CHAR(c),        \
  __VA_OPT__( OBFUSCATE_RECURSIVE LAZY_EVAL (__VA_ARGS__))
#define OBFUSCATE_RECURSIVE() OBFUSCATE_STRING

#define OBFUSCATE(...) { __VA_OPT__(EXPAND(OBFUSCATE_STRING(__VA_ARGS__))) '\0'}

const char text[] = OBFUSCATE('T', 'e', 'x', 't');
```

This works around the limitations, that macro expansion isn't recursive by deferring evaluation of macro expansion until EXPAND.
Note, that this limits macro expansion to some depth. If you start seeing your macros again, higher the number of EXPAND_ calls.

See also: [Recursive macros via __VA_OPT__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51166178/recursive-macros-via-va-opt/67878835#67878835)

Alternatively, you might achieve it with your build system. Either you are modifying the source, or defining a macro with -D... .

Comment: I updated the question to show what kind of modification I want

Comment: @PanJanek Do you want to "obfuscate" the string in the source code or in the executable or in some output?

Comment: yes I want to obfucate strings in the resulting binary.

Comment: @PanJanek Is that a feature, that you need, because strings need to be in a special format or are you trying to achieve "security"?

Answer (score 0):

The C preprocessor simply lacks a feature for doing something like that. If you want that to be done then you have to write your own little preprocessing tool that needs to be executed in a prebuild step for generating the modified source files which are included in your project afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

this is relatively simple to do once you agree to hard-code the length of the string. The hard requirements is that you *have to* hard-code the string length, because it is not possible to get it in preprocessor. Having the string length, you call the proper macro and expand the chain however you want.

I would first start with a boilerplate FOREACH macro that calls a function with an index and two arguments. As we know the length at preprocessor time, we can call the proper overload `FOREACH_##strlen` statically.

For the requirement of hardcoding string length, I would throw in a static assertion, making sure you have to change it when you change the string.

```
#define FOREACH_0(f, a, b)
#define FOREACH_1(f, a, b)   f(0, a, b),
#define FOREACH_2(f, a, b)   FOREACH_1(f, a, b) f(1, a, b),
#define FOREACH_3(f, a, b)   FOREACH_2(f, a, b) f(2, a, b),
#define FOREACH_4(f, a, b)   FOREACH_3(f, a, b) f(3, a, b),
#define FOREACH_5(f, a, b)   FOREACH_4(f, a, b) f(4, a, b),
#define FOREACH_6(f, a, b)   FOREACH_5(f, a, b) f(5, a, b),
#define FOREACH_7(f, a, b)   FOREACH_6(f, a, b) f(6, a, b),
#define FOREACH_8(f, a, b)   FOREACH_7(f, a, b) f(7, a, b),
#define FOREACH_9(f, a, b)   FOREACH_8(f, a, b) f(8, a, b),
#define FOREACH_10(f, a, b)  FOREACH_9(f, a, b) f(9, a, b),
#define FOREACH_N(_10,_9,_8,_7,_6,_5,_4,_3,_2,_1,...)  FOREACH_##N
#define FOREACH(f, a, b, ...) FOREACH_N(__VA_ARGS__,_10,_9,_8,_7,_6,_5,_4,_3,_2,_1)(f, a, b)
    
#define STATIC_ASSERT(...)  \
    sizeof(struct{_Static_assert(__VA_ARGS__); int dummy;})

#define MODIFY_CB(idx, str, num)  str[idx]^num

#define MODIFY(str, strlen, num)  { \
    FOREACH_##strlen(MODIFY_CB, str, num) \
    0 * STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(str) == strlen + 1) \
    }

char text[] = MODIFY("test text", 9, 10);
```

Expanding the code to handle more cases is trivial - it's just adding more `FOREACH_*`.

Notes: identifiers starting with `_` and upper case letter are reserved, you are not allowed to define `_MODIFY`, do not use such identifiers.